# Facebook-SDK for Android: would expect much higher numbers for in app purchases

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-sdk-4.x

I have an Android app with Facebook SDK 4.6.0. We updated to 4.36.1 which should enable automatic In App Purchase tracking.

Now we see the first numbers coming in, but according to Google Play Developer Store they should be much, much higher (~ 30x). Update rate to the newest app version is very good (~ 65%). So tracking seems to work basically, but the numbers are very low...

What could I be missing here?

Comment: Do you have IAP bundles? This could confuse the numbers. Or there is some kind of reporting lag.